# PutItem with DynamoDB using lists / arrays

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to achieve something that I assumed would be pretty standard, but I've hit a wall with it. I have a bunch of data coming at me that I want to store in DynamoDB

```js
    const putDataParams = {
        TableName: "sensorNodeData2",
        Item: {
            "deviceId":   {"S": event.deviceId}, 
            "timeStamp":   {"N": event.time},
            "rssi": {"S": event.rssi},
            "seq":  {"S": event.seqNum},
            "payload": {"L": payloadArrayInt16.map(x => x.N)}
        }
    };
    console.log('Data PutItem Params = ' + JSON.stringify(putDataParams));

    dynamodb.putItem(putDataParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
            context.succeed('SUCCESS');
        }
    });
```

The problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the list part to work. I've defined it first as :

```
var payloadArrayInt16=  new Uint16Array(dataArrayMaxIndex);
```

and the error is:

```
"errorMessage": "ERROR: Dynamo failed: InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item[payload].L to be an Array"
```

Then I tried :

```
var payloadArrayInt16= [dataArrayMaxIndex];
```

Which went through, but obviously doesn't do what I want... when I print out the params, it's not pulled out the contents of the array. It sees:

```
"Temp":{"L":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}
```

I'm pulling my hair out. There isn't a single example anywhere on how to do this. Can someone please put me out of my misery?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DynamoDB array of numeric values is represented like this:

```
"payload": {
    "L": [
      {
        "N": "1"
      },
      {
        "N": "2"
      },
      {
        "N": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now if your input array payloadArrayInt16 is like this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

You have to transform it to dynamo db format:

```
payloadArrayInt16.map(x => { return { "N": x.toString() }});
```

But you can make your life much easier by using [this official aws dymanodb js library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)
It handles all transformations between native js object structures to dynamo db data structures and viceversa.

Also if you are using [AWS IoT Core](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=eu-central-1#/home) you can write your data to dynamodb directly without any lambda.

Comment: Crumbs. You've hit the nail on the head. Thanks heaps!

Comment: And you're totally right. DocumentClient worked perfectly for putting items into the database. The reason I didn't use it was I couldn't get it working for querying and kind of gave up on it... Maybe I'll give it another whirl.

Comment: DynamoDB data representation with its {name -> value} AttributeValues: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html